# Golang program giving incorrect result in Windows 10

Tags: go

First of all, I am a newbie to Go programming. I have a simple Golang program which is giving the correct output in Linux environment but not in my Windows 10 PC.

The code is as follows:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    fmt.Print("Enter text: ")
    text, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
    tarr := strings.Split(strings.Trim(text, "\n"), " ")

    for i := 0; i < len(tarr); i++ {
        num, _ := strconv.ParseInt(tarr[i], 10, 32)
        fmt.Println(num)
    }

    fmt.Println(tarr)
    reader.ReadString('\n')
}
```

If I enter 1 2 3 as input from the terminal, I am getting the following output in Windows 10 (go version go1.12.5 windows/amd64):

```
1
2
0
]1 2 3
```

I am getting the following output in Linux Elementary OS (go version go1.12.5 linux/amd64)

```
1
2
3
[1 2 3]
```

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Comment: have you tried doing `go build` and then executing the `.exe` file?

Comment: @ParnabSanyal Yes I have tried doing that and I am getting the same results in the Windows 10 PC.

Comment: Don’t ignore the errors, windows uses `\r\n` for newlines.

Comment: I am not getting any errors in the terminal @JimB

Comment: You’re ignoring the error value from `ParseInt`. Try printing the literal string you read.

Comment: @JimB It worked when I added \r\n. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While UNIX (and Linux) have a line ending of `\n` Windows has a line ending of `\r\n`. This means that the line you've read on Linux is `1 2 3\n` while on Windows it is `1 2 3\r\n`. If you now remove the `\n` (i.e. `strings.Trim(text, "\n")`) and split by space you get `1`, `2` and `3` on Linux but you'll get `1`, `2`, `3\r` on Windows.

`ParseInt` on `3\r` returns `0` and likely returns an error - which you explicitly ignore. That's why you get the output of `1`, `2` and `0` on Windows. Also, the array on Windows will be printed as `[1 2 3\r]`. Since `\r` sets the output cursor to the beginning of the current line and does not move to the next line (that's what `\n` would do) this effectively overrides the initial `[` with the final `]`, resulting on a visible output of `] 1 2 3`.

Comment: beautifully explained